# C# accepting the height

Tags: if-statement, nested

Write a program Write a C program to accept the
height of a person in centimeter and categorize the
person according to their height.
Use height less than 150 means dwarf, equals 150
means average height and greater than or equal
165 means tall. Otherwise, it shall print “abnormal
height". Use (a) a "nested-if" statement;
Using nested if we can't use if else

Answer (score 0):

You could use a series of if statements, like this:

if (height < 150) {

```
printf("dwarf");

}

else if (height == 150) {

printf("average height");

}

else if (height >= 165) {

printf("tall");

}

else {

printf("abnormal height");

}
```